# What's the deal with As Per Se?

Tags: grammar

I've always used *As Per Se* in a sentence and assumed it was right. I googled it out on a whim and couldn't find it anywhere. I did find *Per Se* and it's variants. Would someone shine some light on this?

Comment: Don’t use *as* before *per*.

Answer (score 1):

The correct expression  is [per se](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/per+se) :

> - (adv.)
>     Of, in, or by itself or oneself; intrinsically. (TFD)

[Etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Per%20se&searchmode=none)

> - Latin, literally "by itself;" translating Greek kath auto (Aristotle).

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=per%20se%2C%20as%20per%20se&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cper%20se%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20per%20se%3B%2Cc0) per se vs as per se.

Comment: As Josh61 illustrated it is lower case; he also noted it is Latin, and since it has not been fully assimilated into English, the style guides I have seen say to use italics to denote it is a foreign word: _per se_.